# Delphi and Google credential

Tags: delphi, google-cloud-datastore

I'm testing "TMS Cloud Pack for FireMonkey", "TTMSFMXCloudDataSet" with Google Datastore

In Google console I created "Client ID for Web application" credential (OAuth 2.0 client IDs), datastore and kind.

I set "Client ID" and "Client secret" info in APPIDS.INC file.

After run program I pressed 'Connect' and get errors:

> Important notice] For the Windows platform, THE TRIAL VERSION OF THE Tms Cloude pack... does not support authentification throught the built-in webbrowser. The TMS Cloud Pack uses the Cromium Embeded Framework and the license prevents binary/trial distribution.

What this mean? What type of credential I have to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you need to buy a license for "TMS Cloud Pack for FireMonkey" in order to be able to use the authentification.